# Google Publisher API in node JS to publish updated AAB, Nothing visible on play console

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client, google-publisher-tag

I'm using googleapis in node.js to publish my updated application. I've done everything like giving permission and enabling APIs. I've used following steps:-

1. Get an authorization token
2. Created new edit
3. Uploaded my AAB file
4. Track the app to production
5. Committed the edit.

I got 200 response in each and every case and if I try to update the edit again it is showing me that this edit is already committed.

**But I'm not able to see any update on my Google Play Console. Its already 30 hours but I can't see any update there.**

Uploading my code for reference

```
async function uploadAAB() {
let authorize = await client.authorize();

//insert edit
let res = await androidApi.edits.insert({
    packageName: packageName
})
console.log(res.data.id)


var aab = require('fs').createReadStream('./app.aab');
const res2 = await androidApi.edits.bundles.upload({
    editId: res.data.id,
    packageName: packageName,
    media: {
        "mimeType": 'application/octet-stream',
        body: aab
    }
});
console.log(`Result ${(JSON.stringify(res2))}`);

const res3 = await androidApi.edits.tracks.update({
    editId: res.data.id,
    packageName: packageName,
    track: "production",
});
console.log(`Result ${(JSON.stringify(res3))}`);

const res4 = await androidApi.edits.commit({
    editId: res.data.id,
    packageName: packageName
});
console.log(`Result ${(JSON.stringify(res4))}`); 
}
```

Since no API failed I can say that everything was fine but I can't see any update on my google developer console after 30 hours.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was in the track code.. I was not sending requestBody params in the parameters..
After adding the requestBody params, It worked perfectly and app was visible on play console instantaneously.